# Get cellular unique identifier

Tags: asp.net, uniqueidentifier

I build an application that among other things send link (SMS) to users.
When user opens the link (asp.net page) she fills a form and send it to server.

In order to make the user submit the form once I need a unique identifier for her cellphone.

Any idea regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: How about their phone number. I'm guessing that it is quite unique since I always get the right person on the phone when I call a specific number.

Comment: That would be great if I could get the phone number from C# or javascript

Comment: You have to click a link, that link can contain a querystring with the number so that the server can pick that up.